# How to integrate Swagger-ui for Restlet webservice in Java?

Tags: java, rest, restlet, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to implement **Swagger-ui** for our **restlet** webservices. Is there any steps that can I follow to integrate swagger-ui in our project?

I have tried following code - 
**Application class**

```
public class DemoApplication extends SwaggerApplication {

    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {       

        Router baseRouter = new Router(getContext());
        DemoResource demoRestlet = new DemoResource(
                getContext());
        demoRestlet.setApiInboundRoot(this);
        attachSwaggerDocumentationRestlets(baseRouter, "/api-docs",
                demoRestlet, "/api-docs/{demo}", demoRestlet);
        return baseRouter;
    }
}
```

**Resource Class**

```
public class DemoResource extends SwaggerSpecificationRestlet {

    public DemoResource(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Representation getApiDeclaration(String category) {
        try {
            ApiDeclaration apiDeclaration = new JacksonRepresentation<ApiDeclaration>(
                    super.getApiDeclaration(category), ApiDeclaration.class)
                    .getObject();
            // manipulate the API declaration object as you wish
            apiDeclaration.setBasePath("demo");
            return new JacksonRepresentation<ApiDeclaration>(apiDeclaration);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SimpleRestlet</display-name>

<!-- Application class name -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>
            deepu.example.DemoApplication
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Restlet adapter -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Catch all requests -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But when I run the project using **Apapche-Tomcat** and hit the url

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/api-docs
```

It is not showing any ui in browser. Do I missing anything or am I following any wrong steps?

Please help me to integrate Swagger-ui for restlet webservice
Your help matters more.

**UPDATE**

My project's directory tree looks like -

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about swagger-ui? Restlet offers a way to generate Swagger specs from the code, but I don't think it exposes the swagger-ui. That's a separate project that you'd need to integrate using other methods.

Comment: I want UI like swagger-ui, I thought restlet provides this ui ! btw how can I integrate ui for restlet webservice.

Comment: Do you use maven in your project?

Comment: No, I'm using simple jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project already maps the content of '/*' to the JAX-RS Servlet.

Clone [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and copy the contents of the /dist directory into a new directory under your WebContent directory, for example /WebContent/ui. You'd probably want to change the `url` parameter of the SwaggerUi object in the index.html to point at your documentation, in your case it would be `http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/api-docs`.

Then, to your web.xml add the following for proper routing:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The UI will be hosted under the context root at the directory you gave it. Following the example above, it would be hosted under `http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/ui`.

Comment: I already copied the contents of 'dist' folder to WEB-INF folder. But when I hit the url -http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/api-docs it shows 
{"apis":[],"apiVersion":"1.0","info":{"description":"","title":"deepu.example.DemoApplication@128c29f"},"swaggerVersion":"1.2"}

Comment: That's not the URL you need to hit. You need to go to http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet or http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/index.html.

Comment: How do you generate your war? There's a mistake in the answer but I need that info.

Comment: Well I run it in Eclipse by right-clicking on project and then Run As -> Run On Server.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The files should be hosted under the WebContent directory and not the WEB-INF.

Comment: I tried by putting files in both folders one by one but still it is not working

Comment: Without a sample project it would be difficult to say what's wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I'm also not understanding. I will update my question with screenshot of my project's folder structure

Comment: The /dist files are under WEB-INF. They need to be under WebContent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71154/discussion-between-deepu-and-ron).

Comment: Yes I have tried that also to move /dist files to WebContent folder but same result

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help, I can access swagger-ui with http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/ui/index.html this url. Currently it is showing no webservice list, I have to look into it. You helped me lot :)

Comment: Make sure you modify the `url` parameter as pointed in the answer.

Comment: Yes I have pointed it to http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/api-docs/, but it  is showing message "Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestlet/api-docs/"

Comment: Remove the slash from the end.

Comment: It is shwoing "fetching resource list:" for long time with no output

Comment: Your application currently doesn't really expose any APIs.